# Detecting if a line whether a line runs from one vertex to another completely within a polygon

Tags: java, math, vector, polygon, path-finding

I'm working with a case in path finding in java, in which I need to detect, whether a line intersects a polygon, for which I test, if the line intersect any of the polygons edges; but because I need to hop from vertex to vertex, I need to allow the corners of the polygon. Unfortunately this also allows an edge from a vertex to another that lies completely inside the polygon.

Example:
[image: Example]

I'm looking for a way to detect this case. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your example isn't quite clear, which line and poly edge are you refering to? The only line that partially follows a poly edge would be the one from the left most vertex to the top right one.

Comment: What you could do is check whether that line intersects the polygon at a vertex (in your case the center of the dent) and if the (absolute) direction of the vector described by the line matches the (absolute) direction of one of the edges that use that vertex that should be the case you're after.

Comment: I am referring to the lines going straight through the polygon, splitting it. You can walk from corner to corner between two polygons or along an edge of one polygon. This is a screenshot from what I have working so far, I'll have to apologize for the unclear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case when diagonal does not intersect edges, additionally check whether middle of this diagonal lies inside polygon
(for example, using famous [ray-edges crossing method](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html))